# Combining result from Flux to result from Mono

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I started using Project reactor and one place where I'm struggling little is how do I combine things coming from Mono with Flux. Here's my use case:

```
public interface GroupRepository {
       Mono<GroupModel> getGroup(Long groupId);
}

public interface UserRepository {
       Flux<User> getUsers(Set<Long> userIds);   
}

Mono<GroupModel> groupMono = getGroup(groupId);
Flux<User> userFlux = getUsers(Set<Long> users);
//run above instrtuction in parallel and associate user to group.
```

Now what I want to achieve is:

How can I combine response from UserFlux and associate those users with that group, with something like group.addUsers(userfromFlux).

Can someone help with how to combine results coming from userFlux and groupMono. I think I use something like Zip but then it does one to one mapping from source. In my case, I need to do 1 to N mapping. Here I have one group but multiple user that I need to add to that group. Is it a good idea to return `Mono<List<Users>` and then use zip operator with both mono and provide a combinator as mentioned here
 `public static <T1, T2, O> Flux<O> zip(Publisher<? extends T1> source1,
            Publisher<? extends T2> source2,
            final BiFunction<? super T1, ? super T2, ? extends O> combinator)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `Flux.combineLatest` static method could help you there: since your `Mono` only ever emits 1 element, that element will always be the one combined with each incoming value from the `Flux`.

```
Flux.combineLatest(arr -> new Combination((GroupModel) arr[0], (User) arr[1]),
                   groupMono, userFlux);
```

Comment: But I ended up using `Flux.zip(groupMono, userMono, BiFunction)` since in my case, underlying data structure inside group model was HashSet ( which holds users which are part of the group) and it's not thread safe to add users flowing from user flux in group, in a reactive fashion. So rather I'm using BiFunction to populate users in group in that separate method. Thanks for the help, really appreciate your help!

Comment: Maybe I don't get something but if I use `combineLatest` with a `Flux` and a `Mono` for this isn't it possible that I "drop" the first events in the `Flux` if the first event of the `Mono` is coming in later?
For example: 
The user repository is super fast an already returned 10 users before the group repository returned the one group then I would expect that the first the first element in the stream behind `combineLatest` is a combination of the 10th user with the group because `combineLatest` actually combines the *latest* elements. Can someone clear this up to me?

Answer (score 10):

This 1 to N mapping sounds similar to a question I gave an answer to here:

[Can you Flux.zip a mono and a flux and and repeat the mono value for every flux value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742934/can-you-flux-zip-a-mono-and-a-flux-and-and-repeat-the-mono-value-for-every-flux/61832225#61832225)

Incase that link goes down, here's the answer again. I don't think this method would have good performance as the mono would be recomputed every time. For better performance, if your Mono is wraps around a slow operation, it might be good to have some caching layer.

Suppose you have a flux and a mono like this:

```
 // a flux that contains 6 elements.
 final Flux<Integer> userIds = Flux.fromIterable(List.of(1,2,3,4,5,6));

 // a mono of 1 element.
 final Mono<String> groupLabel = Mono.just("someGroupLabel");
```

First, I'll show you the wrong way of trying to zip the 2 which I tried, and I think other people would try:

```
 // wrong way - this will only emit 1 event 
 final Flux<Tuple2<Integer, String>> wrongWayOfZippingFluxToMono = userIds
         .zipWith(groupLabel);

 // you'll see that onNext() is only called once, 
 //     emitting 1 item from the mono and first item from the flux.
 wrongWayOfZippingFluxToMono
         .log()
         .subscribe();
```

[image: wrong way]

```
 // this is how to zip up the flux and mono how you'd want, 
 //     such that every time the flux emits, the mono emits. 
 final Flux<Tuple2<Integer, String>> correctWayOfZippingFluxToMono = userIds
         .flatMap(userId -> Mono.just(userId)
                 .zipWith(groupLabel));

 // you'll see that onNext() is called 6 times here, as desired. 
 correctWayOfZippingFluxToMono
         .log()
         .subscribe();
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
Flux.fromIterable(List.of(1,2,3,4,5,6))
      .zipWith(Mono.just("groupLabel").cache().repeat())
```

will zip your label to each value emitted by flux

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer for other folks, I used, `Flux.zip(groupMono, userMono(holding list of users), this::biFunctionToPopulateGroupWithUsers)`. I used this approach rather than as suggested by @Simon, since underlying group that holds users is a `HashSet` and adding users in a reactive way will not be thread safe. But if you've a thread safe data structure I would use suggestion by @Simon.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked both answers and there seems to be a bit of confusion regarding the goal:

- Evaluating a Mono once and combine these results with the Flux. Then repeat/cache is the way to go.
- Combining a Mono with a Flux and re-evaluating it every time. Here the trick is to create a tuple of two Monos: One from the Flux value and one that should be called. To do some calculations afterwards, use map and re-combine with the desired operation.